# Centering tabular array of images

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I have a tabular array of four images and I am not able to center it. My images are pushed towards the right edge of the sheet. The centering looks fine for single images , so I am guessing this issue is of centering starting from the margin. How do I make an visually pleasing centering of my images.

```
\begin{center}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\textbf{blah}  & \textbf{text} $m=\pi,n=e$  \\
\includegraphics[height=45mm]{liss0.png} &
\includegraphics[height=45mm]{liss1.png} \\ 
\includegraphics[height=45mm]{liss2.png} & 
\includegraphics[height=45mm]{liss3.png} \\
\textbf{text} & text

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

I would not mind if my image breaks a little off into the left margin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's by no means necessary to insert `tabular` environments in `table` environments. It appears that you are trying to typeset a "here table", so that it can't float. Then

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cc@{}}
\textbf{blah}  & \textbf{text} $m=\pi,n=e$  \\
\includegraphics[height=45mm]{liss0} &
\includegraphics[height=45mm]{liss1} \\ 
\includegraphics[height=45mm]{liss2} & 
\includegraphics[height=45mm]{liss3} \\
\textbf{text} & text
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

is probably what you need. In case you are satisfied with making the images sticking into the margins, add `\makebox[0pt]{` in front of `\begin{tabular}` and the closing `}` immediately following `\end{tabular}`.

However, this might spoil your pagination, if this object falls near a page break. You may consider to use a floating `table` environment and the **subfig** or **subcaption** packages.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option using the `subcaption` package which egreg mentioned. From the documentation:

> After loading the subcaption package the new environments subfigure and subtable
>   are available, which have the same (optional & mandatory) arguments as the minipage
>   environment. Inside these environments you use the ordinary \caption command for
>   typesetting captions.

**example**
(not from documentation)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \rule{30pt}{20pt}
        %\includegraphics[height=45mm]{liss0.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \rule{30pt}{20pt}
        %\includegraphics[height=45mm]{liss1.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure} \\
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \rule{30pt}{20pt}
        %\includegraphics[height=45mm]{liss2.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \rule{30pt}{20pt}
        %\includegraphics[height=45mm]{liss3.png}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

- remove the `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` instructions
- insert the instruction `\centering` right before `\begin{tabular}`
- insert a `\\` after the final "text" string and remove the blank line before `\end{tabular}`

I notice that the text header for the second column is quite a bit wider than the one for the first column; depending on the width of the graphics files, this may also affect the visual appearance of the efforts to place the images on a sheet of paper.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
\begin{table}[!htb]\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c c@{}}
\textbf{blah}  & \textbf{text} $m=\pi,n=e$  \\
\includegraphics[height=45mm]{liss0} &
\includegraphics[height=45mm]{liss1} \\ 
\includegraphics[height=45mm]{liss2} & 
\includegraphics[height=45mm]{liss3} \\
\textbf{text} & text
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and if the images wider than 0.5\textwidth then you should use

```
\includegraphics[height=45mm,width=0.49\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{...}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @egreg suggested (and this was also the solution that first came to my mind :) ), here is an example using `subfig`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
%%----start of first subfigure----
    \subfloat[Caption of subfigure 1]{%
        \label{fig:volt1cnv}%% label for first subfigure
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{liss0.PNG}}
    \hspace{0.02\linewidth}
%%----start of second subfigure----
    \subfloat[Caption of subfigure 2]{%
        \label{fig:crt1cnv}%% label for second subfigure
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{liss1.PNG}}\\
%%----start of third subfigure----
    \subfloat[Caption of subfigure 3]{%
        \label{fig:volt1cnv}%% label for first subfigure
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{liss2.PNG}}
    \hspace{0.02\linewidth}
%%----start of fourth subfigure----
    \subfloat[Caption of subfigure 4]{%
        \label{fig:crt1cnv}%% label for second subfigure
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{liss3.PNG}}
    \caption{Caption of entire figure}
    \label{fig:vi1cnv}%% label for entire figure
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note that the captions for the subfigures are optional parameters. So if you choose not to have any subfigure captions simply omit that one, like here:

```
\subfloat{%
    \label{fig:crt1cnv}%% label for second subfigure
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{liss3.PNG}}
```